# Как заменить GetChild?

Tags: c#

Есть в общем такой незамысловатый скрипт:

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Block"))
    {
        Instantiate(block, transform.GetChild(0).position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Не знаю как переписать его так, чтобы он обращался не к дочернему объекту, а к обычному (который так сказать не застакан, не знаю как правильно выразиться)

Comment: `transform.position`, не?